# Help with gravitational waves plot/animation with Schwarzschild metric using xAct package and ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, physics, animation, xact

**Update:**
I have now successfully derived the gravitational wave equation. I used [this template](https://www.madscitech.org/GRCalcs.pdf) with slight modifications. The screenshot of success is shown below, followed by the code. Now I need help continuing the code to plot/animate the gravitational waves.
[image]

```
<< xAct`xCoba`;
<< xAct`xTensor`;
<< xAct`xPert`;
DefManifold[M, 
4, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Delta], \[Mu], \[Nu]}];

DefMetric[-1, g[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]], cd]

DefMetricPerturbation[g, h, \[Epsilon]];

Perturbed[Riemanncd[-\[Alpha], \[Beta], -\[Gamma], \[Delta]], 3];

Collect[ExpandPerturbation[%], \[Epsilon], Simplification];

h[LI[2], -a, -b]

Perturbation[g[-a, -b], 1]

Perturbation[g[a, b], 1]

firstorderonly = h[LI[n_], __] ⧴ 0 /; n > 1

Perturbed[g[-a, -b], 1]

DefTensor[sf[], M, PrintAs -> "\[Phi]]"]

DefTensorPerturbation[pertsf[LI[order]], sf[], M, 
PrintAs -> "\[Delta]\[Phi]"]

DefScalarFunction[V]

DefConstantSymbol[ massP, PrintAs -> "mp"]

Clear[L]

L =  Sqrt[-Detg[]] (massP^2 / 2 RicciScalarcd[] - 
1/2 cd[-\[Beta]][sf[]] cd[\[Beta]][sf[]] - V[sf[]])

Clear[varL]

varL = L // Perturbation // ExpandPerturbation // ContractMetric // 
ToCanonical


0 == VarD[pertsf[LI[1]], cd][varL]/Sqrt[-Detg[]] /. 
delta[-LI[1], LI[1]] -> 1  // ToCanonical
```

I am attempting to derive and solve the gravitational wave equations for the Schwarzschild metric and visualize the gravitational waves using ListPlot3D. I am using the [package xAct](http://www.xact.es/index.html) for this, and building off a template. I would like the animation to show the evolution of the gravitational waves over time. There are problems with the code. ListPlot3D is giving me some trouble so I can not do the plot/animation, and there might be other problems with the code. I need some help correcting the code. I am very new to xAct, both; xTensor, and xCoba.

This is my first time using any of these packages.

To try this code please don't forget to [add the xAct package to your addons folder](http://www.xact.es/download/install).

Ok, the code directly below uses xCoba, and the one below this one uses xTensor.

```
    << xAct`xCoba`

    DefManifold[M, 4, IndexRange[a, l]]
    DefChart[ch, M, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]}]

    metric = {{-(1 - 2 M/r[]), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/(1 - 2 M/r[]), 0, 0}, 
    {0, 
    0, r[]^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, r[]^2 Sin[\[Theta][]]^2}}
    perturbation = {{0, h[t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]], 0, 
    0}, {h[t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]], 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
    0, 0, 0}}

    DefTensor[G[-a, -b], {M, M}, Symmetric[{-a, -b}], PrintAs -> "G"]
    DefTensor[T[-a, -b], {M, M}, Symmetric[{-a, -b}], PrintAs -> "T"]

    eqs = EinsteinBasis[metric + perturbation, G[-a, -b]] == T[-a, -b]
    sols = SolveAlways[eqs, Coordinates[ch]]

    (*Specify the values for the mass and time*)
    M = 1; (*Mass of the central object*)
    tVal = 0; (*Time*)

    (*Evaluate the solutions at a specific time and mass*)
    hSol = h[tVal, rVal, \[Theta]Val, \[Phi]Val] /. sols /. M -> M /. 
    t[] -> tVal

    (*Define the radial coordinate range and resolution*)
    rMin = 2.1;
    rMax = 10;
    rSteps = 100;
    rRange = Range[rMin, rMax, (rMax - rMin)/(rSteps - 1)];

    (*Define the polar angle range and resolution*)
    \[Theta]Min = 0;
    \[Theta]Max = Pi;
    \[Theta]Steps = 50;
    \[Theta]Range = 
     Range[\[Theta]Min, \[Theta]Max, (\[Theta]Max - \[Theta]Min)/(\
    \[Theta]Steps - 1)];



   (*Evaluate the gravitational wave amplitude at each point in the 
   grid*)
   waveAmplitude = 
   Table[{rVal, \[Theta]Val, 
   hSol /. {r[] -> rVal, \[Theta][] -> \[Theta]Val, \[Phi][] -> 
      0}}, {rVal, rRange}, {\[Theta]Val, \[Theta]Range}]

   (*Reshape the waveAmplitude array for ListPlot3D*)
   reshapedData = Flatten[waveAmplitude, 1];

   (*Plot the gravitational wave amplitude as a 3D plot*)
   ListPlot3D[reshapedData, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {"r", "\[Theta]", "h"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Gravitational Wave Amplitude"]

   (*Animate the gravitational wave*)
   frames = 
   Table[waveData = 
    Table[{rVal, \[Theta]Val, 
      hSol /. {r[] -> rVal, \[Theta][] -> \[Theta]Val, \[Phi][] -> 
         0}}, {rVal, rRange}, {\[Theta]Val, \[Theta]Range}];
   reshapedFrame = Flatten[waveData, 1];
   ListPlot3D[reshapedFrame, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {"r", "\[Theta]", "h"}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Gravitational Wave Amplitude"], {tVal, 0, 1, 0.1}];

   ListAnimate[frames]
```

Below is a previous attempt where xTensor was used.

```
<< xAct`xTensor`

DefManifold[M, 4, IndexRange[a, l]]
DefChart[ch, M, {t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}]

metric = {{-(1 - 2 M/r), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/(1 - 2 M/r), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
r^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2}};
perturbation = {{0, h[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], 0, 
0}, {h[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
0}};

DefTensor[G[-a, -b], {M, M}, Symmetric[{-a, -b}], PrintAs -> "G"]
DefTensor[T[-a, -b], {M, M}, Symmetric[{-a, -b}], PrintAs -> "T"]

eqs = EinsteinBasis[metric + perturbation, G[-a, -b]] == T[-a, -b];
sols = SolveAlways[eqs, Coordinates[ch]]

(*Specify the values for the mass and time*)
M = 1; (*Mass of the central object*)
t = 0; (*Time*)

(*Evaluate the solutions at a specific time and mass*)
hSol = h[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] /. sols /. M -> M /. t -> t;

(*Define the radial coordinate range and resolution*)
rMin = 2.1;
rMax = 10;
rSteps = 100;
rRange = Range[rMin, rMax, (rMax - rMin)/(rSteps - 1)];

(*Define the polar angle range and resolution*)
\[Theta]Min = 0;
\[Theta]Max = Pi;
\[Theta]Steps = 50;
\[Theta]Range = 
Range[\[Theta]Min, \[Theta]Max, (\[Theta]Max - \[Theta]Min)/(\
\[Theta]Steps - 1)];

(*Evaluate the gravitational wave amplitude at each point in the 
 grid*)
 waveAmplitude = 
 Table[{rVal, \[Theta]Val, 
 hSol /. {r -> rVal, \[Theta] -> \[Theta]Val, \[Phi] -> 0}}, {rVal,
 rRange}, {\[Theta]Val, \[Theta]Range}];

 (*Reshape the waveAmplitude array for ListPlot3D*)
 reshapedData = Flatten[waveAmplitude, 1];

 (*Plot the gravitational wave amplitude as a 3D plot*)
 ListPlot3D[reshapedData, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"r", "\[Theta]", "h"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Gravitational Wave Amplitude"]

 (*Animate the gravitational wave*)
 frames = 
 Table[waveData = 
 Table[{rVal, \[Theta]Val, 
  hSol /. {r -> rVal, \[Theta] -> \[Theta]Val, \[Phi] -> 
     0}}, {rVal, rRange}, {\[Theta]Val, \[Theta]Range}];
 reshapedFrame = Flatten[waveData, 1];
 ListPlot3D[reshapedFrame, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"r", "\[Theta]", "h"}, 
 PlotLabel -> StringForm["Gravitational Wave (t = ``)", t]], {t, 0,
 10, 0.1}];

 ListAnimate[frames]
```

Comment: Are you sure everything else is fine? Shouldn't you be loading xCoba not xTensor? And your ChartDef command needs more parameters which is reported as an error. I'm not experienced with xAct though.

Comment: @1729taxi, I am also very new to xAct. I think you might be right. Let me try to correct these.

Comment: @1729taxi You are right xCoba is the way to go. Although, I am still having other problems with the code now.

Comment: Even after needing xCoba it says (on my machine anyway) that ChartDef needs at least 4 parameters and you are calling it with 3.

Comment: @1729taxi Try going to evaluation -> Quit kernel -> local. After you quit kernel. Remove everything from the notebook, then copy the first code in the post and paste it. It has DefChart[ch, M, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]}] which has 4 parameters. Try running this. Run the code. Hopefully it runs but then only says it has trouble plotting/animating.

Comment: I don't have time right now to look at this - but I think you have some severe problems. I don't think there is a function EinsteinBasis in xCoba for instance.